# Implementing Perf Counters

Tags: c#, performance

I have an application in C#, i want to implement perfcounters in this application so that i can track down the performance parameters and use them to make my application have better performance as of now the application has performance issues.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance counters only tell you that your program is slow.  They don't tell you *why* your program is slow.  Use a profiler.

Comment: ++ You're right, although the words "slow" and "profiler" give me an itch. I've never seen code that was slow. I have seen code that was extremely unnecessary. And lots of things call themselves profilers, but only some are actually very effective.

Answer (score 1):

this is great tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/perfcounter.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class. [Samples here](http://dotnetperls.com/stopwatch).

Answer (score 0):

To paraphrase @Hans, there's a world of difference between *measuring* performance problems and *finding* them, in spite of what is popularly said. [Here's discussion of all that, and directions telling how to do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343)